# write on a 3d element with react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

in react three fiber, how can I write on a 3d element?

I have an element with children: 'Ecran', 'Ecran2', 'Ecran3' and 'Ecran4'. How could I put a text on one of these screens that would stay attached to the screen even if it moved?

```js
 if (loaderGltf){
    loaderGltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.name === 'Ecran1') {
      const objectDirection = child.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3());
      if (objectDirection.z * 10000000 > -4 &&  objectDirection.z  * 10000000 < -2.74){
        child.scale.set(1.7, 1.7, 1.7)
        child.position.set(0, 3, 0)
      } else {
        child.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
        child.position.set(0, 5.198303699493408, 0)
      }}
    else if (child.name === 'Ecran2') {
      const objectDirection = child.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3());
      if (objectDirection.z * 10000000 > -1.26 &&  objectDirection.z  * 10000000 < 1.27){
        child.scale.set(1.7, 1.7, 1.7)
        child.position.set(0, 3, 0)
      } else {
        child.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
        child.position.set(0, 5.198303699493408, 0)
      }}
    else if (child.name === 'Ecran3') {
      const objectDirection = child.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3());
      if (objectDirection.z * 10000000 > 2.75){
        child.scale.set(1.7, 1.7, 1.7)
        child.position.set(0, 3, 0)
      } else {
        child.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
        child.position.set(0, 5.198303699493408, 0)
      }}   
    else if (child.name === 'Ecran4') {
      const objectDirection = child.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3());
      if (objectDirection.z * 10000000 > -1.26 &&  objectDirection.z  * 10000000 < 1.27){
        child.scale.set(1.7, 1.7, 1.7)
        child.position.set(0, 3, 0)
      } else {
        child.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
        child.position.set(0, 5.198303699493408, 0)
      }}
})}
```